# SSLHandshakeException in Tibco BW

Tags: ssl, tibco, businessworks, tibco-business-works

I have been facing an SSLHandshakeException while trying to connect from Tibco BW to an external vendor. I understand that this error usually occurs due to a mismatch in the certificates installed on either of the systems. But i would like to know specifically for which side is this SSL exception exactly occuring?

Also as a part of resolution for which side should the certificates be changed or updated ? I have also attached the full log message. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: `I have also attached the full log message`  where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suspect that the issue is not related to the certificates. If your BusinessWorks application did not trust the external vendors certificate you would get an entirely different error message.

A more likely suspect would be that your BusinessWorks application and the external vendor server could not find a matching protocol that both sides accept (such as SSLv3 or TLSv1). Try connecting using your favorite web browser or use tools such as openssl to find out which protocols the server supports.

**Update**:
Try to execute the following commands and see if you get a handshake failure for any of them

```
openssl s_client -connect server:port -ssl2
openssl s_client -connect server:port -ssl3
openssl s_client -connect server:port -tls1
```

As an example, BW does not support SSL 2.0, so if that is the only protocol the server supports you need to modify the default security provider by setting the following property to your deployed .tra file

```
java.property.TIBCO_SECURITY_VENDOR=j2se
```

Comment: could you please let me know how do i test the same using the tool openSSL. I tried with the below command :
s_client -connect <<Vendor server>>:<<VendorPort>>